# Yet another NSInternalInconsistencyException, but using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I've gone through many of the questions/answers related to NSInternalInconsistencyException / NSFetchedResultsController, but I can't find anything to help me solve my problem.

I get this error after deleting a row in my TVC: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0**

Here's the method in charge of performing the deletion on the data source

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        Role *roleToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Deleting: %@", roleToDelete.name);
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:roleToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        // Delete the row from the data source
        // [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self performFetch];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

My *Exception Breakpoint* stops at the last line of this method.  The weird thing is that the debugger says that I'm deleting two rows, which I'm not:

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
>   (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
>   before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or
>   deleted from that section (0 inserted, 2 deleted)

The next time I start the app, it is clear that only one row was deleted.

Here are the other methods that could cause a problem:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}
```

Comment: I think self.fetchedResultsController is your local array and you are not removing data from this. You have delete it from self.fetchedResultsController.

Comment: @fibnochi: `self.fetchedResultsController` is an [`NSFetchedResultsController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetched results controller (FRC) updates the table view automatically if an object
is inserted, deleted or changed. Therefore,
you just have to delete the object:

```
Role *roleToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:roleToDelete];
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Everything else (`beginUpdates`, `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:...`, `endUpdates`)
is done in the FRC delegate methods (`controllerWillChangeContent:`, `didChangeObject:...`,
`controllerDidChangeContent:`). It should also not be necessary to call `performFetch`.

In your case, `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:...` is called twice: Once in your `commitEditingStyle:` method and a second time in the FRC delegate method `didChangeObject:...`. This causes the "internal inconsistency exception".

Comment: That was a simple solution.  Thanks for your help, it's not the first time you've offered it :)